# link to specific slide from another page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a slideshow in one of my pages and in each slide of the slideshow there is a link to any other pages of my websites. After navigating to other pages, there is a back button and a next button that can navigate users back to the slideshow. The problem is whenever I click the back button, the slideshow restart from the beginning. I want the slideshow to continue from the point where I stopped without having the slideshow to restart from the beginning every time i navigate to it.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
var timer = null;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var indicators = document.getElementsByClassName("indicator");
  if (n == undefined) {
    n = ++slideIndex;
  }
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < indicators.length; i++) {
    indicators[i].className = indicators[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  indicators[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  timer = setTimeout(showSlides, 15000);
}

function plusSlides(n) {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="mySlides fade" id="slide1" data-timeout="5000">
      <div class="intro">
        <img src="image/logoGeo.png">
        <h1>Geo Millennium Sdn Bhd</h1>
        <div class="tips">
          <h2>Tips on How to Use This Slideshow:</h2>
          <p>Click on the title in each slides to view more about the services we provide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="slide2" class="mySlides fade" data-timeout="5000">
      <a href="webpage/RetainingWall.html">
        <div class="para">
          <p>Retaining Wall</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <img src="image/wall3.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade" id="slide3" data-timeout="5000">
      <a href="webpage/SlopeRepair.html">
        <div class="para">
          <p>Slope Repair</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <img src="image/slope8.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade" id="slide4" data-timeout="5000">
      <a href="webpage/SteepSlopes.html">
        <div class="para">
          <p>Steep Slopes</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <img src="image/stepslope1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade" id="slide5" data-timeout="5000">
      <a href="webpage/SlopeProtection.html">
        <div class="para">
          <p>Slope Protection</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <img src="image/image2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade" id="slide6" data-timeout="5000">
      <a href="webpage/ReliefStructure.html">
        <div class="para">
          <p>Relief Structure</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <img src="image/reliefstructure3.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade" id="slide7" data-timeout="5000">
      <a href="webpage/SoilNailing.html">
        <div class="para">
          <p>Soil Nailing</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <img src="image/soilnailing9.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade" id="slide8" data-timeout="5000">
      <a href="webpage/REWall.html">
        <div class="para">
          <p>RE Wall</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <img src="image/REWall1.jpeg">
    </div>

    <a class="previous" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>
    <div class="navigator">
      <span class="indicator" onclick="currentSlide(1)"><h5>Home</h5></span>
      <span class="indicator" onclick="currentSlide(2)"><h5>Retaining Wall</h5></span>
      <span class="indicator" onclick="currentSlide(3)"><h5>Slope Repair</h5></span>
      <span class="indicator" onclick="currentSlide(4)"><h5>Steep Slopes</h5></span>
      <span class="indicator" onclick="currentSlide(5)"><h5>Slope Protection</h5></span>
      <span class="indicator" onclick="currentSlide(6)"><h5>Relief Structure</h5></span>
      <span class="indicator" onclick="currentSlide(7)"><h5>Soil Nailing</h5></span>
      <span class="indicator" onclick="currentSlide(8)"><h5>RE Wall</h5></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to want to store that *active slide index* somewhere.

I suggest looking into utilizing Query Strings (examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) since you mentioned this can redirect to your different "websites" (i.e., different domains).

Simply add a query string to your redirect link, for example:

```
<a href="http://mywebsite.com?activeSlide=2"></a>
```

Where 2 is the active slide on your page that contains the slider. When you go back to your page simply read the active slide Query String parameter using:

```
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

var slideIndex = urlParams.get('activeSlide'); // this is the active slide

// your current code below

var timer = null;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function showSlides(n) { ... }
```

Comment: I actually succeeded in doing the back button using localstorage and I am currently working on the next button. I previously think of the way of adding hash behind each active slide but i could not manage to do it. I will try ur method.Thanks in advance.